# Why is my phone missing "product" partition contained in lineageos distribution?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, lineageos

I have a OnePlus 7T, and am trying to install lineageos on it. The adb sideload method failed, and a forum comment led me to look into doing a manual installation using fastboot as described in https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/hotdogb/fw_update.

After extracting the images from the lineageos hotdogb distribution using payload-dumper-go, and also extracting the images from oxygen updater package for OnePlus 7T for comparison purposes, it appears that each image should correspond to a flash partition on the phone.

When I attempt to fastboot flash the partitions from the lineageos distribution, this completes successfully for most of these partitions, except "product.img", for which fastboot fails with the message

```
"remote: 'Partition not found'"
```

This happened for a couple other images as well (recovery, system_ext, vbmeta_system). Similarly I found that the Oxygen distribution I mentioned earlier contains an image "opproduct", which gives the same message.

From adb if I run

```
ls /dev/block/by-name
```

I can see that the flash attempts that succeeded do have a partition listed here, but the ones that failed don't. How are these partitions created? Can I add the missing ones for the lineageos distro .img files myself somehow?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the last 3 weeks? I current have the exact same issue for the same reason, just a "7T Pro" instead of a "7T" (which seems to be almost identical). Otherwise, did you ask this somewhere else as well, so that I can follow that, too?

Comment: In case you're using Windows, [this post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-stock-fastboot-op7t-stock-fastboot-roms-for-oneplus-7t.3979213) might lead to a solution for you. It links another post, which talks about "large address aware", something about 32bit vs. 64bit software, and links to [this tool](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/large-address-aware.112556). Since it seems to be Windows-specific, I did not look further and also couldn't test it.

Comment: Created this now: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/fastbootd-cant-find-product-partition.4381139

Comment: Apparently I have a "OnePlus 7 Pro", not a "OnePlus 7T Pro". I bought that accidentally, but the specs are fine. Actually following the instructions for the correct device worked, who would have thought…

Comment: My device is definitely a 7T which I also bought accidentally. I gave up on searching the xda-developers forums, seems the topics there are mostly people looking for quick and easy fixes without any useful information.